# How to remove &nbsp; using xslt?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am transforming XMLHttpResponse text to HTML using XSL Transformation. Source page contains `&nbsp;`. I want to remove these characters. 
I added following code to my XSL Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
 <!ENTITY nbsp "&#xa0;">
]>
```

It removed the inline `&nbsp;` but did not remove the `&nbsp;` characters came from XML Response.

I have copied the div tag using

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$div[contains(@class,'maincontent')]"/>
```

How can I remove this?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: I am using Version 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

Does your source document include a definition of the nbsp entity?

If it does, your XSLT stylesheet will see the expansion of the entity (which means it never knows that there was an entity reference there in the first place). Perhaps the entity expands to an xA0 character (which is how this entity is defined in HTML), and you want to remove the xA0 character? In that case, use the translate() function.

If it does not, the XML parser will throw an error and the XSLT will never get to see the document at all.